# what does ~ mean in makefile or shell command?

Tags: bash, makefile

Can somebody explain the mean of the following code in makefile?

```
@mv $$@~ $$@
```

After some search I suppose it means the shell command:

```
mv $@~ $@
```

But what is a `$@~`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a **bash script** more than a makefile.

`$@` represents all of the current command-line arguments (of the current script) serialized to a text list.

`~` at the *start* of a filename, it will be expanded and generally refers to your `$HOME`. *Tilde Expansion* [Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html)

`~` at the *end* of a filename it's just a normal character. *Convention means it's a backup file* [Reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76189/what-does-the-tilde-mean-at-the-end-of-a-filename)

Thus `mv $@~ $~` command will

1. accept a list of filenames as arguments
2. convert backup files back to non-backups

---

If you have this directory:

```
/foo.txt~
/bar.txt~
/baz.txt~
```

Then running the command:

```
./yourscript.sh foo.txt baz.txt
```

The directory contents will change to:

```
/foo.txt
/bar.txt~
/baz.txt
```

Comment: `$@~` expands `$@` first (leaving word-splitting and globbing issues aside), which means that only the _last_ argument ends in `~`; try `set -- a b; echo $@~`.